# Квадраты вместо шрифтов font awesome 5 при локальном подключении

Tags: шрифты

Вроде путь указал правильно:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome/all.min.css"/>
```

и иконку прописываю соответственно 5 версии:

```
<i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
```

Иконку бесплатную выбрал. Через cdn все работает, но мне локально нужно.

Может чего то не хватает?
Хотя по сути все должно работать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: charset UTF-8 в заголовке присутсвует?

Comment: Покажите расположение папок в вашем проекте.

Comment: Или попробуйте подключить из нета.

Comment: @Eugen, да, конечно

Comment: @VerNick, добавил у вопросу изображение.хотелось бы все таки локально чтобы не нагружать страницу

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков А из нета работает?

Comment: @VerNick,да через cdn работает

Comment: а пути самих шрифтов совпадают с указанными в css?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, вы имеете в виду путь, в css файле через который работаю со стилями?

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков Попробуйте вынести сам файл фонтов и подключиться к нему напрямую.

Comment: @VerNick, не помогает

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков У вас неправильный Windows )))

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков в файле `fontawesome/all.min.css` прописаны пути `@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');` и т.д. т.е. файлы шрифтов должны лежать в каталоге fonts в корне

Comment: для 5 версии может другой путь. посмотрите в css

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Точно, как я мог забыть)

Comment: @DmitryKozlov то есть должно быть такое расположение fonts/fontawesome/all.min.css ?

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков нет. css файл пусть лежит, где лежал. Вам надо поместить файлы шрифтов (*.eot, *.woff, *.woff2, *.ttf, *.svg) в каталог fonts в корне вашего проекта

Comment: @DmitryKozlov,спасибо огромное помогло! Может еще сказать,какой мне нужно оставить формат чтобы иконки были как шрифты,как обычные буквы? хотелось бы удалить лишнее так как весят слишком много

Comment: В браузере само определится в зависимости от стилей и размеров текста. Все сразу загружаться не будут